# crontab why executes script every 2 minutes?

Tags: linux, cron

Why it executes the script every 2 minutes?
Shouldn't it execute every 10 minutes ?

```
*\10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /var/www/py/LSFchecker.py
```

Comment: Because `"\" != "/"`.  Perhaps the `\10` is being evaluated as a binary number?  At any rate, it's invalid/undocumented notation AFAICT, so you should just replace it with something correct.  Se Jon's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
*\10 * * * *
```

Should probably be

```
*/10 * * * *
```

Comment: Depending on your cron implementation, I'm surprised you were even able to install a crontab that had `*\10` in it. Most cron implementations I've used won't even let me install it if the syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /usr/bin/python /var/www/py/LSFchecker.py